# Set up email forwarders for domains hosted on AWS

Tags: email, amazon-web-services

I have a domain (`example.com`) hosted with a registrar that doesn't allow me to set-up email forwarders if I use my own nameservers. Since the website is hosted on AWS, I obviously have to use Amazon's nameservers at the registrar. I cannot change my registrar or my hosting provider.

What I want is to set up a few email addresses (`sales@example.com`, `support@example.com`) that will forward all the emails received to another address (`example@gmail.com`). I am not interested in sending emails from the addresses that have forwarders, they are only receiving addresses.

I have found a few tutorials that talked about Amazon [WorkMail](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/10/amazon-workmail-now-supports-email-redirection-to-external-email-addresses/) and Amazon [SES](https://medium.com/@ashan.fernando/forwarding-emails-to-your-inbox-using-amazon-ses-2d261d60e417), but I don't think they were what I am looking for. They seem to be overkill for my needs.

How can I set up simple email forwarders for addresses belonging to domains hosted with AWS?

Comment: Have you asked your registrar if they offer MX records for the forwarding service? Are you certain you need to use Route 53? (It's possible something like a `CNAME` in your registrar's DNS offering might suffice, for example...)

Answer (score 0):

Do you host the other email with another vendor orbit is going to a free Gmail account(or something similar)?

If it is hosted with another vendor I would include the domain as a secondary domain and have an alias for the emails you want to receive. This should not cost anything additional to what you pay.

If you are not paying for any other email service the best solution I can come up with is to use Google apps and create one user for your self ($5/month) and you would have a couple options on how to make the other emails with out cost anymore. 1) add the emails to your user account as alias 2) create 2 groups to receive the emails that would allow you to share the massages in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can't. AWS does not provide simple email forwarding at this time, so you will want to find an external service that does.